# Is it possible to read PVclock from user space?

Tags: kvm, time, xen, clock

Is it possible to read clocksource xen or kvmclock using some user space tool?

Referring to `/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource`. Reading the actual value of the pvclock.

Or would one have to write a C program or use a memory debugger so
something of that sort?

Answer (score 0):

hwclock(8) appears to read the hypervisor's clock

```
# hwclock --show --debug
hwclock from util-linux 2.20.1
Using /dev interface to clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 0 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 0 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on unknown time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2015/08/10 15:07:13
Hw clock time : 2015/08/10 15:07:13 = 1439219233 seconds since 1969
Mon 10 Aug 2015 16:07:13 BST  -0.225494 seconds
#

# hwclock --show
Mon 10 Aug 2015 16:08:52 BST  -0.271426 seconds
mintvm ~ #
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me from inside Xen VMs. I guess hwclock is different from pvclock.
`sudo hwclock --debug --show`
`hwclock from util-linux 2.25.2`
`hwclock: cannot open /dev/rtc: No such file or directory`
`No usable clock interface found.`
`hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.`


`cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource`
`xen`

Comment: [No usable clock interface found](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107481/34446)